# How to ensure template parameter is non-const and non-reference

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

Often (most of the time?) when creating types with template type parameters you want to ensure the type parameter is filled in with a non-reference, unqualified (non-const, non-volatile) type. However, a simple definition like the following lets the user fill in any type for `T`:

```
template <typename T>
class MyContainer {
    T* whatever;
    T moreStuff;
};
```

Modern C++ has concepts that should be able to take care of this problem. What is the best (and preferably least boilerplate-y) way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a concept for this.

```
template <typename T>
concept cvref_unqualified = std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, T>;
```

```
template <cvref_unqualified T>
class MyContainer {...};
```

Comment: Concept should have a "meaning" though, for me. Especially when we have subsumption rules in mind.

Comment: @Jarod42 Arguably the standard concepts have the same problem, e.g. `derived_from`. But yes, OP could wrap this concept in something like `concept MyContainerElement`...

Comment: Here, we have also composition of several traits, which is not reflected by the concept. and a reflection should be done (by OP, depending of the needs) to know if that concept should be split or not to allow subsumption.

Answer (score 5):

[`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) is a good option:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class MyContainer
{
    static_assert(!std::is_reference_v<T>);
    static_assert(!std::is_const_v<T>);
    static_assert(!std::is_volatile_v<T>);

    T* whatever;
    T moreStuff;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the type via `static_assert` like

```
template <typename T>
class MyContainer {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>, T>, "T must be non-reference, unqualified type");
    T* whatever;
    T moreStuff;
};
```